# How to get the window title for a matplotlib window using QT4Agg

Tags: python, matplotlib

Before I used TkAgg and I set the window title with `fig.canvas.set_window_title`. I retrieved the title with `fig.canvas.manager.window.wm_title()`.

After changing to QT4Agg I can still set the window title with `fig.canvas.set_window_title` but I can't get the title with `fig.canvas.manager.window.wm_title()`.

How can I get the title?

Answer (score 2):

Under Qt4Agg you can get the window title with

```
fig.canvas.manager.window.windowTitle()
```

ps: you can get all function the `window` object offers by inspecting it from the python prompt:

```
>> import inspect    
>> inspect.getmembers(fig.canvas.manager.window)
```

This will print all methods and properties ypu can access.